# How to protect Jasper Generated Report when using XLSX as output?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, excel-2007

I have problem related to file protection when changed the Jasper Report output from xls to xlsx.

The changes is needed since XLSX  could support greater row (Up to 1.000.000) compared to XLS.

The problem is  the report need to be protected. This is an easy task since Jasper Configuration support this by using

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.password" value="password" />
```

http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.password

But This doesn't work when the output is XLSX, i try to use trivial such as  change from xls to xlsx and the result is remain the same.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.password" value="password" />
```

How to protect Jasper Generated Report when using XLSX as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can make  yourself (after digging in JR sourcecode) only [JExcelApiExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JExcelApiExporter.html) and [JExcelApiMetadataExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JExcelApiMetadataExporter.StyleInfo.html) classes use ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.password`*** property. And only this two exporters (not JRXlsxExporter and not even JRXlsExporter) can set password.

The snippet from [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JExcelApiExporter.html):

```
protected void setParameters()
{
    super.setParameters();

    if (createCustomPalette)
    {
        initCustomPalette();
    }

    password = 
        getStringParameter(
            JExcelApiExporterParameter.PASSWORD,
            JExcelApiExporterParameter.PROPERTY_PASSWORD
            );

...

}

private final void setSheetSettings(WritableSheet sheet)
{
    PageOrientation po;
    PaperSize ps;

    if (jasperPrint.getOrientationValue() == OrientationEnum.PORTRAIT)
    {
        po = PageOrientation.PORTRAIT;
    }
    else
    {
        po = PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE;
    }
    if ((ps = getSuitablePaperSize(jasperPrint)) != null)
    {
        sheet.setPageSetup(po, ps, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        sheet.setPageSetup(po);
    }
    SheetSettings sheets = sheet.getSettings();
    ...
    if(password != null)
    {
        sheets.setPassword(password);
        sheets.setProtected(true);
    }
...
}
```

You can write your own XlsxExporter.

The JRXLSExporter uses [POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) and the JExcelApiExporter uses the [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).